# Why did she do it?

Tags: lateral-thinking

My friend asked me this question while morning walk, I was not able to answer. (am happy that i didn't, will tell you the reason later).

> A woman was attending her mother's funeral. She meets a man she's never seen before. She believes him to be her soulmate and falls in love with him. But she forgets to ask for his number, and when the day is over, she can't track him down. A few days later she murders her sister.
>    Why?

---

p.s. : Try to answer it with the first thing which comes to your mind!

> I've searched for the actual source, will be adding it after it is answered.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please specify a logical explanation for the downvote ?

Comment: I know this has been posted before, but it got deleted.

Comment: Previous post: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28831/

Comment: how am I supposed to know if it got deleted ?

Comment: You aren't. I know because I voted to close and delete it.

Comment: Yes precisely. [edit] Delete it ? Why so??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43389/discussion-between-abcdexter-and-f).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She kills her sister because

> that's the only way she knows to find the man again.  Since she doesn't have his number, she must create a new funeral for him to attend so they can meet again, and so callously murders her own sister to create a hookup opportunity.

You're glad you didn't think of this because

> it's horrible.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can see [this](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2012/oct/07/wisdom-of-psychopaths-kevin-dutton-review), and [this](http://www.snopes.com/medical/myths/psychopathtest.asp) for the further explanation 0:)

Answer (score 2):

Because she realized

> he might be a relative or someone close to her family since he attended the funeral. So she thought she can meet him again if another funeral rakes place in her family and she killed her sister for that.

You were happy that you didn't answered because,

> this is a psychological question to find criminal mind :P

Comment: You are absolutely correct :) Although the statement about [criminals is overrated](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2012/oct/07/wisdom-of-psychopaths-kevin-dutton-review).